# jquery.animate(), strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Here is a little sample. The two `div`s are supposed to float to center after clicking it, while the other one should disappear. After clicking the "x", it should go back to status quo. This works fine for both, except that for the right `div`, the animation has a strange behaviour.

It is the first time I'm trying to do something with `animate()`, so maybe I oversee somethin obvious. As you can see after clicking the "x" on the right `div`, it first moves to the bottom of the page, and after that it moves to the right place (which is pretty ugly). All I do in `animate()` is resetting the changed values to default, like on the first `div`. As in the first `div` I change only the margin, it pretty sure has something to do with the changing of the height. How can I suppress this behaviour and let it move directly to that position?

Browser: Firefox 16.0.2
[fiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/tF4RU/)

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Welcome to BetManager</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link href="css/mainContent.css"    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/headContent.css"    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/welcome.css"        type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/welcome.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="mainContainer">
            <div class="headContentContainer">

            </div>
            <div class="mainContentContainer">

                <div id="welcomeLogin" class="welcomeInnerContainer">
                    <div class="firstView" id="firstViewLogin">
                        default Image Login
                    </div>
                    <div class="afterView" id="afterViewLogin">
                        <div id="cancelLogin">
                            x
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="welcomeRegister" class="welcomeInnerContainer">
                    <div class="firstView" id="firstViewRegister">
                        default Image Register
                    </div>
                    <div class="afterView" id="afterViewRegister">
                        <div id="cancelRegister">
                            x
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**welcome.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // login panel
    $("#firstViewLogin").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeRegister").hide();
        $("#welcomeLogin").animate({
            marginLeft:'35%'
        });
        $("#firstViewLogin").fadeOut(500);
        $("#afterViewLogin").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $("#welcomeLogin").hover(function(){
            $("#welcomeLogin").addClass("welcomeInnerContainerHovered");
        },
        function(){
            $("#welcomeLogin").removeClass("welcomeInnerContainerHovered");
    });

    $("#cancelLogin").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeLogin").animate({
            marginLeft:'15%'
        });
        $("#afterViewLogin").fadeOut(500);
        $("#firstViewLogin").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        $("#welcomeRegister").show();
    });

    // register panel
    $("#firstViewRegister").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeLogin").hide();
        $("#welcomeRegister").animate({
            marginRight:'35%',
            height:'80%',
            marginTop:'5%'
        });
        $("#firstViewRegister").fadeOut(500);
        $("#afterViewRegister").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $("#welcomeRegister").hover(function(){
            $("#welcomeRegister").addClass("welcomeInnerContainerHovered");
        },
        function(){
            $("#welcomeRegister").removeClass("welcomeInnerContainerHovered");
    });

    $("#cancelRegister").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeRegister").animate({
            marginRight:'15%',
            height:'60%',
            marginTop:'10%'
        });
        $("#afterViewRegister").fadeOut(500);
        $("#firstViewRegister").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        $("#welcomeLogin").show();
    });

});
```

**welcome.css**

```
body{
    background: #EEEEEE;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 900px;
    min-height:900px;
    margin:auto;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.mainContainer{
    width: 80%;
    height:96%;
    min-height:96%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:2%;
}

.mainContentContainer{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height:90%;
    min-height:80%;
    margin:auto;
}

.welcomeInnerContainer{
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 10%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.headContentContainer{
    background: #999999;
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
}

.welcomeInnerContainerHovered{
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 10%;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #777777;
}

#welcomeLogin{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

#welcomeRegister{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

.afterView{
    display: none;
    cursor: default;
}

#cancelLogin{
    margin-left: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#cancelRegister{
    margin-left: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;  
}
```

Comment: Would be a huge help if you could maybe create a Fiddle that reproduces the problem (or just link to your site)?

Comment: oh, didn't know that solution, see editet question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/TFtMq – dbaseman

You may first want change thing like this to use callback function (A function to call once the animation is complete). http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```
$("#firstViewLogin").fadeOut(500);
$("#afterViewLogin").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
```

to

```
$('#firstViewLogin').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $("#afterViewLogin").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: really nice, the edit from your fiddle did the thing. Why is that causing the problem? I understand that it's cleaner to use callback methods, but why is that causing the div to first go to bottom?

Comment: @Valentino Ru .. Are you still having a issue when using this (http://jsfiddle.net/TFtMq) link provided by @dbaseman?

Comment: No, like mentioned that was the solution. I wanted to give him time to post his solution as answer.

Comment: @ValentinoRu The problem is just that when you use fadeIn, the left panel immediately becomes visible, so it displaces the registration panel. That's the cause of the weird jerky behavior. Moving the fadeIn call to animate's complete handler ensures that the panel only re-appears once the right panel is safely in place off to the right.